# Does Protractor 4 has any dependency?

Tags: protractor, npm-install

I have been using protractor 3.3.0 and finally decided to move up to V4. I am behind a firewall, so using proxy setup. That setup works fine for v3.3.0, but I am not able to download any of V4. It always results in ECONNREFUSED with error

```
error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket cound not be established, cause connect ECONNREFUSED <ip>:<port>"
```

is there any difference on how to download Protractor V4 and above? I have tried

```
npm install protractor (my package.json had "protractor": "^4.0.0")
npm install protractor (my package.json had "protractor": "4.0.4")
npm install protractor@4.0.0
npm install protractor@4.0.4
```

When I couldn't install it, I moved back to v3.3.0.. my package.json has "protractor": "^3.2.2")

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is a common one when connecting through proxies. Please see [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2472) for the discussion
And yes there are new dependencies/new versions of old dependencies in Protractor@4.0.4 which will trigger new downloads.

PLs see below for specific details
`

```
npm view protractor@4.0.4 dependencies

{ 'adm-zip': '0.4.7',
  chalk: '^1.1.3',
  glob: '^7.0.3',
  jasmine: '2.4.1',
  jasminewd2: '0.0.9',
  optimist: '~0.6.0',
  q: '1.4.1',
  saucelabs: '~1.3.0',
  'selenium-webdriver': '2.53.3',
  'source-map-support': '~0.4.0',
  'webdriver-manager': '^10.2.2' }



npm view protractor@3.3.0 dependencies

{ 'adm-zip': '0.4.7',
  chalk: '^1.1.3',
  glob: '~6.0',
  jasmine: '2.4.1',
  jasminewd2: '0.0.9',
  optimist: '~0.6.0',
  q: '1.4.1',
  request: '~2.67.0',
  saucelabs: '~1.0.1',
  'selenium-webdriver': '2.52.0',
  'source-map-support': '~0.4.0' }
```